# Install third party libs, package management, application folder structure in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I've been studying `Erlang` for a while, and want to write a small sample `Erlang` application, but I do not know how to do it, I mean more `Erlanglish` way.

How to install third party libs? Something like `npm install` for node.js

What is the recommended folder structure?

Is there some sample yet classical `Erlang` application demonstrate it, that I can learn from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way of installing an Erlang application is to *avoid* using a 3rd party packaging system as of now. We don't have a package manager (note the date of this post, it might change in the future). Rather, we rely on a tool like `rebar` to *package* what we call a **release**.

A release is a packaging of needed libraries, with correct versions into a standalone version of the Erlang system in a separate directory structure. This structure can be zipped and moved to another machine and run by itself.

There are 3 ways to do this: use `reltool` directly use `rebar` to call reltool, or use the newly created `relx` tool to make release assemblies.

The problem with an `npm` like tool is when you need to have different versions of packages that cannot coexist and you need dependency convergence. Currently the "solution" is not to solve it in Erlang.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended directory structure is documented [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#id73974).